# Algorithm for randomly generating reachable platforms

Tags: 2d, mathematics, physics, procedural-generation, platformer

I want to randomly generate reachable platforms on the fly for a 2D game.  Right now, I am just creating platforms at random x,y positions.  Only 4 platforms can exist at once, so once the 5th one is generated the 1st one is removed (fifo).

So, I want to ensure that the player can jump from his current platform to at least one other at any given time.

I was thinking of using some variant of the distance formula to calculate the location of the next platform being generated.  I was hoping someone could help me out with the **formula** for calculating the next platforms possible x,y positions.

The player variables I am assuming will be important are speedX, speedY, and gravity.

From here, I should be able to calculate the maximum distance to plug into the distance formula.

[image]

However, I am thinking that some variation of the distance formula that contains a variable for slope would be better in my case.

I want to ensure that the player will never get stuck on a platform with no where it can jump.  Also, I want to ensure that platforms aren't generated on top of each other.

Formulas/images/code are a huge plus.

Here is how jumping is currently working.

```
Field speedY:Float = 4
Field GRAVITY:Float = .05

Method Update:Void()
    If KeyDown(KEY_SPACE) And not jumping Then
        dy=-speedY
        jumping = true
    EndIf


    If jumping
        dy += GRAVITY
        local tempY:Float = y + dy
        y = tempy
    Endif
End Method
```

Edit:
I now understand that the formula is just the displacement of basic projectile motion.
[image]

[image]

Except, in my case, we don't care about cos/sin because the angle will always be the same.

Comment: Do you use a form of gravity that simulates real-world physics? Or a different variation of gravity?

Comment: No, it is just a very basic implementation of gravity without acceleration or anything like that. dy +=Level.GRAVITY

Comment: When do you begin falling?

Comment: I updated my question with my code around jumping and gravity (collisions removed). Basically, you begin falling once GRAVITY overtakes speedY.

Comment: That is acceleration (The value you add to dy). So my answer will work for you.

Comment: I took the time to clear things up

Comment: I updated it further to make it more accessible. Let me know if you were able to implement it.

Comment: This looks great! :) So x (or currentX) isnt used in either equation? Also, i thout you said xpos depends on ypos? Thank you for the image, it makes things a lot easier to understand. Also thanks for pointing out which values to randomize.

Comment: That was a typo (I added `x`). `Xpos` & `Ypos` depend on each other in the sense that they both depend on `t`. You basically start from either the left or the right side of the platform (that the player is on) and then randomize a reasonable value for `t`. You can compute a position the player can land on using the equation I noted by providing `t`. You may also want to iterate and make sure the path is clear(?) Cause there may be blocking platforms above the one the player is standing on. You can start a new question if you get stuck with that part and see no answer available.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to implement this now :) This is a great solution!

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you on this, but is your equation correct for ypos? I don't see how it could ever create platforms that are above the player's current y position. Currently, in my game the upper left hand corner is (0,0) and the lower right hand corner is (width, height).

Comment: gravity is positive (pulling downwards) 'ypos' and 'vy' is supposed to be negative, pulling upwards. If 'vy' is not negative than you need to subtract it instead.

Comment: Something still isn't right with the ypos. Now the platforms are only generated above the player. I am just using a literal for t right now as I test and will changed to randomized after I verify everything is working. Here is what I am using
    `vy=4
    vx=1
    g=.05
    t=2
    y=11`

    `ypos = (g * t * t) / 2 - vy * t + y
    xpos = vx * t + x`

Comment: If `t = 2`, `vy = 4` and `g = 0.5` than it will never go down.. For it to go down, `t > 2 * vy / g`. Pick a `t` that is at least 16+ in this case. Or just change g to be 2 and increase `t` to 4+

Comment: The parabola currently looks upside down. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8hxlvq8mhr
I replaced "vy" with "v", "y" with "c", and "t" with "x" in desmos.
Also, my map goes from y=0 to y=16 tiles. Or y=0 to y=512 pixels.

Comment: So, using a t too large will give me too large results (unless I divide by TILE_SIZE?). I only want to place the platforms at integer x,y coords. Also, increasing g would make it so my player cannot jump high at all.

Comment: If you want an exact tile you should probably do something like `xpos -= xpos % tilesize;` `ypos -= ypos % tilesize;`

Comment: Comments are not the place for discussion. Please take it to chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Answer:
Lets look at the image. The player (represented by a circle) can jump to the left or to the right. What makes the difference is how much time passes since the moment the play jumps until the moments she lands on another platform.

[image: player jump]

If we randomize a direction, either `left` or `right` and a value for time `t` than we can place a platform in that direction in the correct position.

let:

```
g = Gravity
vx, vy = speedX, speedY
x, y = currentX, currentY // either on the left or the right side of the platform
```

The equation is:

```
ypos = (g * t^2) / 2 + vy * t + y
xpos = vx * t + x
```

Again, all you need to do is randomize a value for `t` and compute the new position.
Remember that ought to keep it small enough so the new platform is within the screen.

Old Answer:
The general idea is checking how much distance you can cover on `x`-axis before reaching a certain `y` altitude (on the way down) that is too low for the platform you want to jump onto.

First, anything within the `x0`, `x1` bounds  of the platform the player is standing on is reachable if it is bellow maximal jump height. If you are using gravity as a simple acceleration downwards then the time it takes a player to reach the peak of his jump is:

`t = speedY / GRAVITY`

This means the player will reach:

`OrigY + t * speedY / 2` at her peak (where `OrigY` is the altitude you jump from). This also means you can have a shot at reaching any platform that is that high if it's `t * speedX` units away on x-axis.

To figure out the equation for lower platforms maximal distance on `x`-axis, you need to remeber you can cover about `t * speedX` by the time you reach your maximal jump height and then begin to fall (`GRAVITY` takes over). Reaching a certain `y` that is `delta` bellow your max height will take:

```
(gt'^2)/2 = delta
t'^2 = (2 * delta) / g
t' = sqrt(2 * delta / g)
```

So if a point is `delta` bellow max height, it can be reached if it is less than `(t + t') * speedX` units away. The equation is:

```
speedX * ((speedY / GRAVITY) + sqrt(2 * delta / GRAVITY))
```

This is of course a "best pixel perfect jump ever" approximation. You may want to give the player a better chance by reducing her `speedY` and `speedX` to 80% or 90% when you compute. Also, it does not take into consideration the possibility of blocking platforms.

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway you could sum this up into two formulas? One for calculating a reachable value for x and one for calculating a reachable value for y?  What I ultimately want to do is randomly place a platform and ensure it is reachable.

Comment: I understand but the reachable x value depends on the y value you pick. If want I could sum it up where given an x value it will return the highest y values (a bit later).

Comment: That would be great.